# What's the horizontal scrollbar appearing on the Feedback part?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

http://whybaguio.com/php/profile/businessprofile.php?id=178

Can someone tell me why is it creating a horizontal scrollbar for the feedback part???? I'm checking the elements but I can't figure it out.

Comment: That code burns my eyes

Comment: Looks like your HTML is malformed, why is your feedback div a child of your map div? You also have a bunch of javascript errors which may be related to this (or other) problems.

Answer (score 1):

Give `overflow-x:hidden` to `#feed`. that is solving the problem.

and also remove `position:absolute` from `.second` class.